# How to center vertically an absolutely positioned scaled element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Without `scale` code works fine, but I need to center vertically an already **scaled** element. I am looking for solution using CSS or JS approaches.
Also I can not use `transform-origin` CSS property because it's unsupported in some browsers that  I need to support...

https://jsfiddle.net/o62ja9r6/17/

```css
.container {
  position: fixed;
  border: 2px dashed blue;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  width: 76px;
  height: 169px;
  background-color: red;
}

.vertical-center {
  top: 50%;
  transform: scale(0.4) translateY(-50%);
  /* transform: translateY(-50%);  // <--- it works */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="slide vertical-center">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Order matters, swap `translateY` with `scale`.

```css
.container {
  position: fixed;
  border: 2px dashed blue;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  width: 76px;
  height: 169px;
  background-color: red;
}

.vertical-center {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) scale(0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="slide vertical-center">
  </div>  
</div>
```

Quick Explination

If you have an element that is `100px` tall and you translate it along the y-axis by `-50%` it will move up 50% of it's height, which would be `50px`. If you scale that `100px` tall element **first**, down to `40%` of it's height, then it will be `40px` tall when you try to translate it along the y-axis, which will only move it up `20px`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `translate` you can use simple `CSS` for this

```
.vertical-center {
  top: 0;
  left:0px;
  bottom:0px;
  right:0px;
  margin: auto;
  transform:  scale(0.4);
}
```

for working demo [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/o62ja9r6/19/)

Comment: There is a problem with your approach: https://jsfiddle.net/o62ja9r6/22/  By some unknown to me reason bottom half of `.slide` container is not taken into account...

Comment: Ya! i agree when width and height is not fixed, then this approach won't work, that time you can use `flexbox`